# nuxt.js and bulma - how to customize css

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, bulma

Im new to both vue.js, nuxt.js and bulma and I'm trying to do simple customizing of style.

I've created a new nuxt.js project and add bulma using https://buefy.github.io/#/documentation/start where I'm trying to set a background image to the `hero`.

Here is my `index.vue` page:

```
<template>
  <section class="hero bg-img">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title">
        Hero title
      </h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle">
        Hero subtitle 
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</template>

<style scoped>
//in custom CSS you need to add
.bg-img {
    background-image: url(~/assets/autumn-tree-5k-new.jpg) ;
    background-color: red;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size:  cover;
    background-color: #999;
}
</style>
```

However, when I view the site in the browser there are no CSS styles for the `bg-img` class.

Comment: Try adding a height and width to the section.

Comment: Checkout these as well: https://dansup.github.io/bulma-templates/templates/hero.html
https://github.com/dansup/bulma-templates/blob/master/templates/hero.html
Pretty nice.